# Prove or disprove that there is an infinite number of even numbers in the decimal expansion of $\sqrt2$.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

> Prove or disprove that there is an infinite number of even numbers in
>   the decimal expansion of $\sqrt2$.

Although I have heard of some conjectures about normal numbers that are still open problems, the condition in this question is weaker. So is the conclusion correct, or is it an open problem?

Comment: It is open, we even do not know for any digit whether it occurs infinite many often in $\sqrt{2}$. We cannot even rule out that eventually the decimal expansion looks like $0,0010100110001\cdots$ with only zeors and ones following forever.

Comment: What we do know that at least two digits appear infinite many often, otherwise the decimal expansion would eventually get periodic, which is impossible because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your informative comments! So what are some other nontrivial results about the numbers in the decimal expansion of an irrational number like, say, $\sqrt2$?

Comment: As already said, we know almost nothing about the long-term decimal expansion of $\sqrt{2}$ and many other irrational numbers like $\pi$ , $e$ or $\gamma$. The last of those numbers is not known to be irrational, but it is widely believed that it is even transcendental.